# lightning buttonIcon are not displaying

Tags: lightning-buttonicon

I wanted to save some space and trade out the standard buttons with labels for x-small button icons.  I originally had the buttons in a grid col, and when I changed to just lightning:buttonIcon they wouldn't display.  After monkeying around with it, I finally just put a new card in the component with just the buttonIcons from the example docs and it still won't work.  What's the problem?

Here's the component mark-up:

```
<lightning:card iconName="standard:data_integration_hub" title="{!v.headerTitle}">

    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:settings" variant="bare" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" alternativeText="Settings" />
    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:settings" variant="bare" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" disabled="true" alternativeText="Settings (disabled)" />
    <!---
    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:left" variant="bare" size="x-small" alternativeText="this"
                                      onclick="{!c.onFirst}" disabled="{! v.currentPageNumber == 1}"/>
    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:chevronleft" variant="bare"
                                      onclick="{!c.onPrev}" disabled="{! v.currentPageNumber == 1}"/>
    -->
 </lightning:card>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:  Apparently it doesn't like the 'variant="bare"' modifier, even though that is exactly what is in the examples found at

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:buttonIcon/example

I'll just make them xtra small and live with the button borders, unless someone has a good suggestion.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using/testing in a stand-alone app, make sure your app extends force:slds, or you won't see anything other than boxes with the alternative text.